# FastAPI exception_handlers and mounted apps

Tags: python, exception, fastapi

I have a FastAPI app :

```py
app = FastAPI()
```

And several mounted apps.

```py
app.mount("app_1", mounted_app_1)
app.mount("app_2", mounted_app_1)
# and so on
```

I defined an exception handler so that a certain class of errors are handled specifically

```py
@app.exception_handler(ValidationError)
async def request_validation_error_exception_handler(
    request: Request, exc: ValidationError
):
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=422,
        content={"message": "validation error"},
    )
```

But it does not seem to cascade on my mounted apps. I would like to avoid defining an exception handler on each of the mounted class. Is there a way to cascade this exception handler ?